# Errors with a calculator using class

Tags: python

I tried making a calculator using class as I am practicing classes, but it spews out a few errors. I am using an answer to another stackoverflow question to help me, but that person was using python2. [Python: using classes outputs an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283675/python-using-classes-outputs-an-error)

```
class Calc:

    operations = ('+', '-', '*', '/', '**')

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.op = None

    def run(self):
        self.prompt_op()
        self.prompt_x()
        self.prompt_y()

        if self.op == '+':
            return self.add()
        elif self.op == '-':
            return self.sub()
        elif self.op == '*':
            return self.mult()
        elif self.op == '/':
            return self.div()
        elif self.op == '**':
            return self.pow()
        else:
            raise ValueError("Wrong operation... ")


    def prompt_op(self):
        self.op = input("Enter an operation: " + ', '.join(Calc.operations))
        if self.op not in Calc.operations:
            raise ValueError("Sorry, wrong operation")
        return self.op


    def prompt_x(self):
        try:
            int(input('Enter the first number: '))
        except ValueError:
            print('Sorry, wrong value')
        return self.x

    def prompt_y(self):
        try:
            int(input('Enter a second number: '))
        except ValueError:
            print('Sorry, wrong value')
        return self.y


    def add(self):
        return self.x + self.y

    def sub(self):
        return self.x - self.y

    def mult(self):
        return self.x * self.y

    def div(self):
        return self.x / self.y

    def pow(self):
        return self.x ** self.y

Calculator = Calc()
print(Calculator.run())
```

Comment: What are the errors? Please show a [mre].

Comment: You are not assigning to `self.x` and `self.y` in `self.prompt_x` and `self.prompt_y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not save the value of `input` into `self.x` and `self.y`, so they keep being `None`. You're `return`ing it but you don't save it there either

Do the following for `x`, and same for `y`

```
def prompt_x(self):
    try:
        self.x = int(input('Enter the first number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Sorry, wrong value')
```

Or

```
def prompt_x(self):
    try:
        return int(input('Enter a first number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Sorry, wrong value')

# run method
self.x = self.prompt_x()
```

---

And for now, if you enter for example letters, you'll get the `'Sorry, wrong value'` and you'll need to run the program again. Add a `while True` loop, and it'll continue to ask until you give a good value that can be converted to `int`

Then use one common method for method, to avoid writing twice the same method

```
def prompt(self, value_type):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(f'Enter the {value_type} number: '))
        except ValueError:
            print('Sorry, wrong value')
```

use like this in `run` method

```
self.x = self.prompt('first')
self.y = self.prompt('second')
```

---

For the operator, it can be simplified, and improved with a `while` loop too

```
def prompt_op(self):
    while self.op not in Calc.operations:
        self.op = input("Enter an operation: " + ', '.join(Calc.operations) + ":")
```

Comment: return self.x or self.y is not necessary now

Comment: Thank you for the help!
And sorry for the bad post

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "use like this in ```run``` method"

Comment: @AbdullahNadeem your method named `run`

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning input `x and y` to the instance variables.

Update your code as below.

```
def prompt_x(self):
    try:
        # added self.x
        self.x = int(input('Enter the first number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Sorry, wrong value')
    # you dont have to return them
    # return self.x

def prompt_y(self):
    try:
        # added self.y
        self.y = int(input('Enter a second number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Sorry, wrong value')
    # you dont have to return them
    # return self.y
```